# Noether normalization and free modules

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, integral-domain, free-modules

Let $A$ be a finitely generated algebra over some field $k$, and assume that $A$ is an integral domain.
By Noether normalization, we have a finite injective ring homomorphism $\varphi: k[x_1, \ldots, x_n] \hookrightarrow A$.

**Is $A$ always a free module over $k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$?**

I know that this fails for arbitrary finite type $k$-algebras, as zero-divisors can produce torsion elements (see e.g. [Can generators of Noether normalization be zero divisors?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4431791/can-generators-of-noether-normalization-be-zero-divisors)). But as $A$ is a domain, $A$ is torsion-free.

The limited amount of examples I tried (coordinate rings of hyperelliptic curves given by $y^2 = f(x)$, the free generators over $k[x]$ being $1$ and $y$) seem to suggest that $A$ is, in fact, free.

Comment: False. If $A$ is free, in particular, it would be Cohen-Macaulay. Find an $A$ which is not.

Comment: Dear @Mohan, how does one see that $A$ would be Cohen-Macaulay if free? I thought that this only holds for local rings...

Comment: Cohen-Macaulay is a local property.